# PyQt5 QTableWidget Right Click on Cell Won't Spawn QMenu

Tags: qt, pyqt, qt5, pyqt5

My program has a table, and there's a desire to be able to right click a cell in said table and have that spawn appropriate actions that will manipulate that cell (different set of actions for different cells). My test code, just has a widget that spawns a table, installs an event filter on the viewport to figure out which cell was right clicked.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QAction, QMenu, QTableWidget, QTableWidgetItem, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5 import QtCore


class TestRightClickTableWidget(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.tableWidget = QTableWidget()
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(4)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(2)
        self.tableWidget.setItem(0, 0, QTableWidgetItem("Cell 1"))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(0, 1, QTableWidgetItem("Cell 2"))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(1, 0, QTableWidgetItem("Cell 3"))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(1, 1, QTableWidgetItem("Cell 4"))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(2, 0, QTableWidgetItem("Cell 5"))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(2, 1, QTableWidgetItem("Cell 6"))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(3, 0, QTableWidgetItem("Cell 7"))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(3, 1, QTableWidgetItem("Cell 8"))

        self.tableWidget.viewport().installEventFilter(self)

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.tableWidget)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

    def eventFilter(self, source, event):
        if(event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonPress and
           event.buttons() == QtCore.Qt.RightButton and
           source is self.tableWidget.viewport()):
            item = self.tableWidget.itemAt(event.pos())
            print('Global Pos:', event.globalPos())
            if item is not None:
                print('Table Item:', item.row(), item.column())
                menu = QMenu(self)
                menu.addAction(QAction('test'))
                menu.exec_(event.globalPos())
        return super(TestRightClickTableWidget, self).eventFilter(source, event)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = TestRightClickTableWidget()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

So I can find the the right cell, and the global position to run exec_ on the menu. But the menu won't show up on the screen. I was wondering if this is a Qt bug where menus won't spawn in a table, or I'm not creating/executing the menu correctly. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try it:

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QWidget, QAction, QMenu, QTableWidget, 
                             QMainWindow, QTableWidgetItem, QVBoxLayout, )
from PyQt5 import QtCore


class TestRightClickTableWidget(QWidget): #(QMainWindow):   # (QWidget): #

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.tableWidget = QTableWidget()
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(4)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(2)
        self.tableWidget.setItem(0, 0, QTableWidgetItem("Cell 1"))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(0, 1, QTableWidgetItem("Cell 2"))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(1, 0, QTableWidgetItem("Cell 3"))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(1, 1, QTableWidgetItem("Cell 4"))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(2, 0, QTableWidgetItem("Cell 5"))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(2, 1, QTableWidgetItem("Cell 6"))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(3, 0, QTableWidgetItem("Cell 7"))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(3, 1, QTableWidgetItem("Cell 8"))
        
        ### This property holds how the widget shows a context menu
        self.tableWidget.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.CustomContextMenu)     # +++
        ### This signal is emitted when the widget's contextMenuPolicy is Qt::CustomContextMenu, 
        ### and the user has requested a context menu on the widget. 
        self.tableWidget.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.generateMenu) # +++

        self.tableWidget.viewport().installEventFilter(self)

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout() 
        self.layout.addWidget(self.tableWidget)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

    def eventFilter(self, source, event):
        if(event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonPress and
           event.buttons() == QtCore.Qt.RightButton and
           source is self.tableWidget.viewport()):
            item = self.tableWidget.itemAt(event.pos())
            print('Global Pos:', event.globalPos())
            if item is not None:
                print('Table Item:', item.row(), item.column())
                self.menu = QMenu(self)
                self.menu.addAction(item.text())         #(QAction('test'))
                #menu.exec_(event.globalPos())
        return super(TestRightClickTableWidget, self).eventFilter(source, event)

    ### +++    
    def generateMenu(self, pos):
        print("pos======",pos)
        self.menu.exec_(self.tableWidget.mapToGlobal(pos))   # +++

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = TestRightClickTableWidget()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]